# How to pass a data to a function under Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following working code that takes a file `mydata.json` and process it under  a function.

```
jQuery(
   function ($) {
   $.get("mydata.json",function(data) {
      // do something with mydata.
    });
});
```

Now instead of a file I'd like to execute that function with a variable directly copied from `mydata.json`:

`var mydata_json = {'foo':[1,2,3]};`

How can I do that?

I tried this but failed:

```
jQuery(
   var mydata_json = {'foo':[1,2,3]};
  function(mydata_json) {
      // do something with mydata.
    }
);
```

Comment: Remove `jQuery(..`, keep only `var mydata_json = {
    'foo': [1, 2, 3]
};
// do something with mydata.`. Use it like normal variable, no need of function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax

```
jQuery(
   function ($) {
   $.get("mydata.json",function(data) {
      // do something with mydata.
    });
});
```

is using an **unnamed** function to process the data.

Being the function without a name and not stored in any scope is however impossible to call it from other places. A very simple solution is to use a named function in the global scope for the processing instead:

```
function processData(data) {
      // do something with data.
}
```

and the call it with the result of a `get` with:

```
jQuery(
   function ($) {
   $.get("mydata.json", processData);
});
```

This way you will be also able to call `processData` with other input you get from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as

```
jQuery(
   var mydata_json = {'foo':[1,2,3]};
   stuff(mydata_json);
);
function stuff(mydata_json)
{
// do something with mydata.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You code:

```
jQuery(
   function ($) {
   $.get("mydata.json",function(data) {
      // do something with mydata.
    });
});
```

is passing a `function` to `jQuery` function. `jQuery` will *save* the function and execute it once the `DOM` is ready. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3)

---

Now think about the syntax of this:

```
jQuery(
   var mydata_json = {'foo':[1,2,3]};
  function(mydata_json) {
      // do something with mydata.
    }
);
```

You already know that it should be something like

```
jQuery(function($){
  var mydata_json = {'foo':[1,2,3]};
  function myFunctionName(mydata_json) {
      // do something with mydata.
    }
  myFunctionName(mydata_json);

});
```

---

OR Simply

```
jQuery(function($){
  var mydata_json = {'foo':[1,2,3]};
  // do something with mydata.
});
```

Now if you want to pass an extra argument to the DOM Ready function, I don't think that's possible. You can but make `mydata_json` global and access it from inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

in this code--

```
jQuery(
 function ($) {
 $.get("mydata.json",function(data) {
    // do something with mydata.
  });
});
```

you are doing all the processing inside an anonymous function. instead you can declare a function and call that.

For ex-

```
function domyjosn(data){
}
```

and you can  call this function.